# How can I check BIT datatype in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, bit

I have a column in `users` table named `permissions`. Like this:

```
// users
+---------+-----------------+-------------+
|   id    | permissions     |    name     |
+---------+-----------------+-------------+
| int(11) | bit(15)         | varchar(20) |
+---------+-----------------+-------------+
| 1       | 001100001111101 | Jack        |
| 2       | 111111111111111 | Peter       |
| 3       | 110000000111011 | Martin      |
+---------+-----------------+-------------+
```

As you can see, `permissions` column has `bit(15)` datatype. Each bit of that value determines one user ability. For example, the first bit refers to `voting`-ability, the second one refers to `commenting`-ability ant etc ...

Also I have a trigger `BEFORE UPDATE` which investigates that permission like this:

```
SELECT permissions INTO @deleting_permission FROM users WHERE id = new.deleter_id;

IF old.deleted <> new.deleted THEN
IF (IFNULL((@deleting_permission & b'10000000000' > 0), 0) < 1) THEN
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = "You cannot delete post";
END IF;
END IF;
```

And always it throws:

> You cannot delete post

Even for **#2 user** which has `111111111111111` permission value. So what's wrong?

---

Noted that I update `permissions` column like this:

```
-- To give some specific accesses (permissions) to the user
UPDATE users SET permissions = b'111111000101011' WHERE id = ?

-- To give full access (permissions) to the user
UPDATE users SET permissions = -1 WHERE id = ?
```

Comment: `SELECT INTO @user_defined_variable` is a very dangerous practice.  If no row is found, any previous value is not overwitten, and these variables have session scope, not program scope.  See https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/35207/11651.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to work with the `BIT` type, then you'll need to use bitwise operators, not regular operators.  For example, if you wanted to check if the user had the left most bit set as a permission, you could do an `&` operation:

```
SELECT permissions INTO @p FROM users WHERE id = new.deleter_id;


IF old.deleted <> new.deleted THEN
    IF (b'100000000000000' & @p = 0)
    THEN
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = "You cannot delete post";
    END IF;
END IF;
```

The basic idea above is that the literal `b'100000000000000'` serves as a *mask* which can be used to detect if the left most bit (and only that bit) is set to 1.  If it were set to 1, then the `&` operation would not return 0.

The reason why a user with `111111111111111` permissions has all rights is that any mask checking a bit would return true.

Comment: There was a typo in my question which is edited now. Sorry

Comment: My answer doesn't really change.

Comment: The OP does use the bitwise operator.

Comment: @Shadow I don't see _any_ bitwise operators being used.

Comment: emm, you know I don't have `active` column. So what should be `@active_deleter` in your condition? `IF (IFNULL(@active_deleter, 0) = 0 OR b'10000000000' & @p = 0)`

Comment: I updated my question.  The basic idea is that you just `&` to appropriate bit mask to your permissions bit column.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen then check again: `IFNULL((@deleting_permission & b'10000000000' > 0)`

Comment: @Shadow This is not the original question as I remember.  The OP edited his code several times.

Comment: The OP edited his question one and checking the history, this is the code from the originsl question: `IFNULL((@active_deleter & b'10000000000' > 0)`, which again used the bitwise operator.

Answer (score 1):

You select the field `active` in the trigger to check permission, but according to your question, the rights are held in the `permissions` field.

Change your query to use the latter field:

```
SELECT `permissions` INTO @active_deleter FROM users WHERE id = new.deleter_id;
```

Also, your `permissions` field has 15 bits. The mask you use has only 10. You should check if you are testing the right bit in the first place.

Comment: This is not a complete answer to the question.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen the OP uses the bitwise operator. That part of your answer is completely superflous.

Comment: There was a typo in my question which is edited now. Sorry

Comment: @MartinAJ then check the mask length

Comment: Your catch on possibly using the wrong size for the bitmask is a good one +1.  It might not have mattered if checking the left most bit, but definitely a potential bug.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen And won't you implement that awesome idea? Because I myself don't understand what's that exactly.

Comment: @MartinAJ Just experiment with the bit shift operators until you see how they work.  We can't do this for you.